# Disallowing overriding virtual method returning const reference with a method returning non-const reference

Tags: c++, c++14

Following code compiles:

```
struct Ret {};

struct A
{
    virtual const Ret& fun() = 0; 
};

struct B : public A
{
    Ret& fun() override
    {
        static Ret ret;
        return ret;
    }
};

int main()
{
    B b;
}
```

How can I disallow overriding method returning reference with a different const specifier for return type during compile time?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: May I ask why you'd want to disallow it? Code that uses the `A` interface will still be getting a const reference.

Comment: `const Ret& fun() { return fun_internal(); } protected: virtual const Ret& fun_internal() = 0;` ? I'm not sure you can completely prevent it...

Comment: I doubt this is useful, but you can check it with CRTP: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/aadc705b9ce67dc6

Comment: Why is it a problem for you? It's not unsafe in any way. The opposite situation would be a problem, but that doesn't compile.

Comment: Hey thanks for replies! 
I was under the impression that since I can't for example override fun with a function returning integer like this: `int fun() override` - obviously it's a different type it should never work at all, the non-const qualified variant should not compile either. Perhaps it is the same type, but by returning const ref I'm restraining the returned object reference from invoking its own non-const methods. I would like future implementers to retain this behavior. The behavior is kept only when using the `A` interface now. This whole thing is just a tad inconsistent is all.

Answer (score 5):

<sub>*All standard references below refers to [N4659: March 2017 post-Kona working draft/C++17 DIS](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/).*</sub>

---

#### The return type of a derived function needs to be covariant with the return type of the function it overrides, but not the other way around

As governed by [[class.virtual]/7](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/class.virtual#7) [extract, **emphasis** mine]:

> The return type of an overriding function shall be **either identical
> to the return type of the overridden function or *covariant* with the
> classes of the functions.** If a function `D​::​f` overrides a
> function `B​::​f`, the return types of the functions are covariant if
> they satisfy the following criteria:
>
> - [...]
> - (7.3) both pointers or references have the same cv-qualification and the class type in the return type of `D​::​f` **has the same
>   cv-qualification as or less** cv-qualification than the class type in
>   the return type of `B​::​f`.

such that the following program is well-formed

```
struct Ret {};

struct A {
    virtual const Ret& fun() = 0;
};

struct B : public A {
    Ret& fun() override { /* ... */ }
};

int main() {}
```

where we may note that polymorphic usage of the `A::fun` interface of an underlying `B` object will enforce the constness of the return type of the interface, whereas the following program is ill-formed:

```
struct Ret {};

struct A {
    virtual Ret& fun() = 0;
};

struct B : public A {
    const Ret& fun() override { /* ... */ }
};

int main() { }
```

which comes with the following instructive compiler error message (Clang)

> ```
> error: return type of virtual function 'fun' is 
>        not covariant with the return type of the 
>        function it overrides
> ```

This requirement comes natural, as we may note that *if* the interface `A` would allow polymorphically invoking the non-const `Ret&`-returning `fun()` even if a derived object implements the overload as returning a `const Ret&`, then we would have a way modify `const` object (through polymorphism), which is undefined behaviour.

---

There are naturally workarounds (e.g. replacing dynamic polymorphism with the [Curiosly Recurring Template Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) and constness assertions on the into-base injected derived type) but these would arguably all seem to address [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) and are likely to implement patterns that only increase the complexity of the code without any apparent gain.

Comment: I was surprised by the fact that this covers as well the case when `class B::fun()` returns a reference to a type derived from `Ret`: [Test on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/701982c42b15c721).

Comment: @Scheff yes, that is governed by [\[class.virtual\]/7.2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/class.virtual#7.2) (omitted in my extract above): _"[...] the return types of the functions are covariant if they satisfy the following criteria: [...] (7.2) the class in the return type of `B​::​f` is the same class as the class in the return type of `D​::​`f, or is an unambiguous and accessible direct or indirect base class of the class in the return type of `D​::​f`"_